# Python - Function isn't 'Global' and so can't be called within Threading Class

Tags: python, multithreading, function

So, first off here's my code:

```
import threading

print "Press Escape to Quit"

class threadOne(threading.Thread): #I don't understand this or the next line
    def run(self):
        setup()

    def setup():
        print 'hello world - this is threadOne'


class threadTwo(threading.Thread):
    def run(self):
        print 'ran'

threadOne().start()
threadTwo().start()
```

So, the problem is that within my class 'threadOne' the run function runs (as that is called by the threading module) but from there I can not called any other functions.  That includes if I make more functions beneath the setup() function.  For example above, in my run(self) function I try and call setup() and get 'NameError: global name 'setup' is not defined'.

Does anybody have any ideas or can they explain this to me?

Sam

Comment: use `self.setup()` (although `setup()` should also take `self` as a parameter since it's an instance method). (As for an explanation; I recommend the python tutorial where classes and instance methods are discussed in detail).

Comment: NB you don't need to subclass `Thread`. You can and should just pass a function (plus arguments, if necessary) to `Thread()`.

Comment: @delnan - I've googled this a lot and can't understand how to do this - could you give another pointe?R

Comment: @SamHeather See the [Thread documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#thread-objects). Specifically, you'd pass a function for the `target` parameter. Your example would become `Thread(target=setup).start()`, with `setup` becoming a module-level function (without parameters) and `threadOne` disappearing completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setup` is a method of your `Thread` instance. Therefore, you call it with `self.setup()` rather than `setup()`. The latter is trying to call a global function named `setup` which does not exist.

Since `setup()` is an instance method, it must accept `self` as its first parameter as well.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you meant to do the following:

```
class threadOne(threading.Thread): #I don't understand this or the next line
    def run(self):
        self.setup()

    def setup(self):
        print 'hello world - this is threadOne'
```

Comment: How do I pass the arguments?

Comment: @VineeshTP Pass them as arguments when you create your Thread class, then access them in the appropriate threaded method